# Asynchronous function not waiting for Promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I've written following asynchronious node.js function, which accesses to my database via Mongoose and thus is an async function):

```
function getWindSpeed(householdID){
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, _){
        const household = await Household.findById(householdID)
        resolve(stoch.norm(household.windSimulation.mu, household.windSimulation.sigma, 1))
    })
}
```

In the other hand, I have following function, which is also async because both accesses to the database and uses the previous function for each element in the database:

```
async function getMeanWindSpeed() {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject){
        let numberOfHouseholds = 0
        let averageWind = 0.0
        console.log('Begin')
        await Household.find({}, async function (error, households) {
            if(error){
                reject(error)
            }else{
                numberOfHouseholds = households.length
                for(let i = 0; i < households.length; i++){
                    const speed = await wind.getWindSpeed(households[i].id)
                    console.log(speed)
                    averageWind += speed

                }
            }
        })
        averageWind = averageWind / numberOfHouseholds
        console.log('Finish')
        resolve(averageWind)
    })    
}
```

As you can see, I iterate over all the elements in the collection and apply the `getWindSpeed()` function, however it doesn't wait for its completion, as I get the following trace based on the `console.log(...)` debug messaged:

```
Begin
Finish
12.2322
23.1123
(more speeds)
...
```

Some more information that may be usefuk:

- I'm awaiting for the result of `getMeanWindSpeed()` in another async function
- I tried to return one hardcoded value for each element in the database (instead of calling `getWindSpeed()` and it worked fined, so I guess the problem is in that function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we don't pass a callback to .find() we'll get a promise returned, this makes the code a lot easier to read.

We could further simplify the function getMeanWindspeed since it becomes a simple wrapper for getAverageWindSpeed();

For example:

```
async function getAverageWindspeed() {
    let numberOfHouseholds = 0
    let averageWind = 0.0
    let households = await Household.find({});
    numberOfHouseholds = households.length
    for(let i = 0; i < households.length; i++){
        const speed = await wind.getWindSpeed(households[i].id)
        console.log(speed)
        averageWind += speed
    }
    return averageWind / numberOfHouseholds;
}

async function getMeanWindSpeed() {
    console.log('Begin')
    let averageWind = await getAverageWindspeed();
    console.log('Finish')
    return averageWind;
}
```

Comment: Your `getMeanWindSpeed()` function is an anti-pattern.  If `getAverageWindSpeed()` returns a promise, there's no need to wrap it in another promise.  Just return the one you already have.

Comment: I just mentioned that above! That's a good point... I believe the function getMeanWindSpeed is basically redundant at that point...

Comment: Similiarly, `House.find()` is probably a database function capable of returning a promise (if no callback is passed to it).  That's how `getAverageWindSpeed()` should probably be fixed.

Comment: That's a great point again... that will make things a bit cleaner.. I'll just make the assumption that if don't pass a callback we get a promise.. I wasn't 100% sure on this. Thanks @jfriend00

Comment: Now, you've got it.  Just eliminate the duplicate copies of `getMeanWindSpeed()` which as you pointed out is now not even necessary.

Comment: oh yes, ta, typo on my behalf :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are mixing await with promise. It is bad practice. If you can do same thing using await and async. See the below example.

```
const fakeDelay = () => new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(() => r("data"), 1000);
})
const Household = {
    findById: () => fakeDelay()
}
async function getWindSpeed(householdID){
    const household = await Household.findById(householdID)
    console.log()
    //stoch.norm(household.windSimulation.mu, household.windSimulation.sigma, 1)
    return household;
}
const main = async () =>{
    getWindSpeed().then(console.log)
}
main()
```

**// notice**

> async function getWindSpeed

will be by default promise

Comment: The phrase "mixing await with promise" makes no sense.  `await` is ONLY useful when you are awaiting a promise.  So, the two MUST be used together.

Comment: yes.. but here it does not make sense. By default everything is promise.

Comment: "By default everything is promise" also make no sense.